# Numeric Input to filter all values >= in a DT as a output

Tags: r, shiny

I am currently developing a new feature into a dashboard (in Rshiny) i have been working on for some time. currently i have all the back end stuff pretty much done but i am getting stuck at creating a numeric input in the UI. I want to allow the user to input a number and then in turn filter all of the rows when the given column is >= to that value.

For the sake of this example lets say the DT looks like:
DT <- c(x,y,z).... want to filter the z based off of the numeric input.

so a simplied version of code is:

```
    DT <-  dbReadTable(my_db, "hist")

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    numericInput("num", label = h3("select to see age increase above ", inputId = 'Value', min = 0),),
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput('Filter')),
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output,session){
  output$Filter <- renderDataTable(
    datatable(
      DT %>% filter((  <=  )),  ### need help here
      caption = 'Growth of Age Greater then User Input',
      selection="single", escape=FALSE, 
      options = list(
        lengthMenu = list(c(5, 15, -1), c('5', '15', 'All')),
        pageLength = 10,
        #remove the search bar in the list
        sDom  = '<"top">lrt<"bottom">ip'
      )
    ),
    server = TRUE
  )
}
shinyApp( ui = ui, server = server)
```

All help is appreciated :)

Comment: Should just be `filter(z >= num)`, change operator as required.

Comment: with reactive functions the syntax change slightly, was where i was struggling.